# Specifying ONE value-parameter on a container-element which is then valid for all included elements

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say you got something like here:

```
Column() {
    Text(text = "Player", color = Color.White)
    Text(text = "0", color = Color.White)
}
```

**Is it possible to specify the color on the Column?** So, that it becomes applied to all contained Text-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a specific content color by wrapping the `Column` inside a `CompositionLocalProvider`:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides Color.White) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Player")
        Text(text = "0")
    }
}
```